# Adding text to the beginning of url with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a bookmarklet. It should test if the url contains a certain word, if not, it will encode it and add some text to the beginning of the url. So far, I have figured out how to test for the word. The code I am using for that is as follows:

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('math') === -1){ 
    alert("Math detected");
}
```

I want to encode the url like this: If the url it detects is this, `http://www.coolmath-games.com/` it should redirect to `tunneler.pw/index.php?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.coolmath-games.com%2F`. Ideally, it wouldn't use regex, but it isn't a big deal if it does.

If it doesn't detect the word, it shouldn't do anything.

**EDIT:** If anyone was curious, here is the code converted to bookmarklet form.

```
javascript:void%20function(){-1===document.location.href.indexOf(%22math%22)%26%26alert(%22Math%20detected%22)}();
```

Comment: You can use encodeURIComponent this

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and I think I got it to work, but the part I was having real trouble with was adding the text to the beginning of the converted url.

Comment: Actually i didnt unserstand would you like to encode url and redict with as query string oarama?

Comment: If `math` has to be part of the domain, you have to match it in the domain part of the url. like if `^(?:https?://)?([^/?]*?math[^/?]*?)(?=/|$)` replace with `tunneler.pw/index.php?q=http%3A%2F%2F$1%2F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('blocked') === -1){ 
    document.location.href = "http://tunneler.pw/index.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
}
```

`encodeUriComponent` will escape the URL, so you will be able to use it in the query string of another URL.

Comment: Could you clarify? What I want to do is, if the url does not contain the word 'blocked,' it should encode the url and add "http://tunneler.pw/index.php?q=" to the beginning of the url. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer to reflect this. It wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: Also, it won't just be for this one "coolmathgames" website, it should work for any. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working as a bookmarklet, even after I convert it. I will have to try it not as a bookmarklet and see what is wrong.

Comment: I just tried it in a Javascript shell and got this error: ReferenceError: encodeUriComponent is not defined

Comment: I fixed a typo in the function name. Now it should work.

Comment: It works now, thank you so much! Accepted as answer.